# Adobe Brackets extension that enables code-folding for Ruby/Chef dev?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, adobe-brackets

I love Adobe Brackets and use it for everything except my Chef dev. The main reason being that I can't find anything that enables code folding for Ruby. Does anyone know of a good extension? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

did you try Atom.io?
It's very powerfull editor with planty of plugins and it has code folding by default for each language.

Comment: Thanks @rafpiek. I have tried Atom.io, but I still prefer Brackets over it. It would be just extra-perfect if it did code-folding on ruby. :-)